# What was the last-starting TV anime to be fully produced using physical cels?

Tags: anime-production, anime-history

By "last-starting" I mean the anime that began airing and/or production most recently.  [This Japanese-language article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170703175911/https://www.asahi.com/culture/news_culture/TKY200708290098.html) seems to state (as best I see via Google Translate) that Sazae-san was the last to have episodes produced using that type of workflow, but it of course *began* production in 1969, so many, many later shows were produced with a fully-cel workflow.

Comment: The shift happened around 1999-2000, but I'm not sure about the last outlier.